# After showing the output the python window closes immediately

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python version 2.7

I tried a code and it was not giving any error. When I ran the program, It showed the result only for a few milliseconds and then the window closed immediately. Is there any method to display the result permanently and to close the window only at my wish rather than it closing all by itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep a Python script output window open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000900/how-to-keep-a-python-script-output-window-open)

Comment: What code? Do you have a minimal example that shows this? What OS? How do you run the code?

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `raw_input()` at the end of you script. This will prompt for a string, and you can close the window then by pressing "Enter"

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are running it by double clicking your .py script. Your OS (Windows I assume) will then close the calling 'cmd' terminal once the script has finished, you could circumvent this by starting the terminal manually (just goto start -> execute and enter cmd) to run the script so it won't close automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your code runs as fast as it can and stops when its finished.
When you open a .py program via double clicking it on a windows OS; it opens the program in a cmd window and when the code is done running it closes the window again. You only specified it to perform some calculation and then stop after that. Therefor in order to keep the program running type `raw_input()` or if using python 3  `input()` at the end of your code in order to prevent it from running all the way through until you press a key.