# Python program crashes when run in Windows CMD when containing this quotation marks “suspects”

Tags: windows, python-3.x, printing, cmd

My python program crashes when run in windows CMD, but doesn't crash in IDLE. I have sought the possible reason and i found that those quotation marks are the cause of the crash.

Here is my code:

```
import time
time.sleep(1)
print('“suspects”')
time.sleep(1)
print('done')
input('finish')
```

What is the reason for that? Those quotation marks are from internet web pages.

update1:
- I didn't know kinds of crash, that is why I ask questions.
- crash means that when run in windows console, the cmd window is closed entirly unexpectedly.

update 2:
this is the output when opening the console then run the script

when run by double clicking the script it is closed unexpectedly. - when opening the console first then run the scrpit (d:\test.py) it gives me : treaceback (most recent call last): file "D:\test.py", line 4, in  print('\u201csuspects\u210d') -- file "C:\pythonn34\lib\encodings\cp720.py", line 21, in encode. --- return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] -- unicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encodez character '\u201c' in position 0: character maps to  --- sorry I couldn't copy and paste it from the console

Comment: Define  'crash'. Do you get a `UnicodeEncodeError` exception, or a blue screen of death? Be *specific*. There are plenty of questions here about printing to the Windows console from Python, by the way, please do search for your error and `print` and `python-3.x`.

Comment: update1: - I didn't know kinds of crash, that is why I ask questions. - crash means that when run in windows console, the cmd window is closed entirly unexpectedly.

python windows cmd

Comment: What happens when you open the cmd window *first*, then run `python.exe yourscript.py` (with full paths as needed)? If you double-click a script, the window doesn't stay open.

Comment: when run by double clicking the script it is closed unexpectedly.
- when opening the console first then run the scrpit (d:\test.py) it gives me : treaceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Post that in your question, you can [edit] it.

Comment: And see [How to keep a Python script output window open?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1000900) for your specific issue that the window closes immediately.

Comment: when run by double clicking the script it is closed unexpectedly.
- when opening the console first then run the scrpit (d:\test.py) it gives me : treaceback (most recent call last): file "D:\test.py", line 4, in <module> print('\u201csuspects\u210d') -- file "C:\pythonn34\lib\encodings\cp720.py", line 21, in encode. --- return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] -- unicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encodez character '\u201c' in position 0: character maps to <undefined> --- sorry I couldn't copy and paste it from the console,

Comment: Use the `[-]` menu to start the copying procedure, then select the text and use the same menu again to grab that text. Yes, you have a `UnicodeEncodeError` because your console doesn't know how to print curly quotes.

Comment: I've duplicated you to the canonical post.

Comment: ok, i'll check for the answer there

Comment: thank you for the new stuff I've learned from discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.x by default does not support unicode characters. To allow them, paste this at the beginning of your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Emisor, the problem is in windows console. the utf-8 didn't fix it. I think it is from the windows cmd. because in idle the program works fine> and it is python 3.x