# Python command opens python command prompt in new window

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I've installed python 2.7 on my machine. Although path variables are set properly, whenever I fire python command, it opens up python prompt in new window. If I try to run it as an administrator, it works fine. But gives an issue for normal user.

Comment: you just need to type python not python.exe

Comment: even python does the same thing..

Comment: which os you are using?

Comment: windows server 12

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53623318/python-exe-opens-in-a-new-console-window

Comment: checked already, it doesn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved, python.exe was by default running as an administrator when python command was fired. Resetting it helped in resolving the issue.

[reference_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACb85.png)