# Pyautogui works in IDLE but not when i execute it as .py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, pyautogui

the code is:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.moveTo(502, 632)
input()
```

it works in IDLE but when i save and run it, the screen flashes and closes. I tried reading it and it said error in line 1. Please Help.

Comment: Try to get more information about the error message. Your top priority is to be able to view it without the window closing. The console tends to vanish abruptly at the end of the program if you initially started the program by double-clicking its icon in a file explorer. Instead, open a command line and execute your program by name.

Comment: Related reading: [How to keep a Python script output window open?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1000900/953482)

Comment: The error message is: Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\dsff.py", line 1, in (modules)
    import pyautogui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'

Comment: ModuleNotFoundErrors usually occur when the module is not installed. It's unusual that the error still appears even if you execute `pip install`. Assuming the install completes with no errors, the next most likely explanation is that you have multiple versions of Python installed, and `pip` is installing to one and not the other. Try to determine whether `pip` and `python` are in the same directory. On Windows, you might try `where pip` and `where python` on the command line.

Comment: I guess they are in the same folder. only after Python35-32 there is python.exe and in pip its scripts/pip.exe

Comment: If you're saying "python's path is Python35-32/python.exe and pip's path is Python35-32/scripts/pip.exe", then I would expect `pip install` to succesfully work. If you're saying "python's path is Python35/python.exe and pip's path is Python32/scripts/pip.exe" then you definitely have more than one Python installed.

Comment: pip install successfully worked, like you said in the first situation.

Comment: Please Help me, I cant fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,
the thing is i had Anaconda distribution of python installed.
Idle was installed in normal python while the when i executed it as .py, anaconda was running it. I just uninstalled anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Please check

1. Your python versions in both places you are running,
2. Whether pyautogui is installed in the env where you are running as .py file

It is running fine in place as .py file

Comment: The python versions are the same and i tried installing it many times using pip install pyautogui, it shows no error.

Comment: Can you share the error it is throwing? May be `pip3 install pyautogui` you will need to do if python version is 3+

Comment: I shared a comment with the error on an other answer, please view that.

Comment: Check if `pyautogui` is present in `pip list`, if it is not there, then there is a problem with `pip install pyautogui`

Comment: AAGH! Its so frustrating, its in there. Still no fix.

Comment: Please Help me, I cant fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your interpreter doesn't have `pyautogui`.

just before run try this: `pip install pyautogui` this required install once.

Comment: Please Help me, I cant fix it.

Comment: @OneChannelEverything what you mean "it didnt work", please give more information.
`- First step run "cmd"`
`- Second step change directory to your script directory "cd <path_to_your_script>"`
`- Third step run your script "python <you_script.py>"`
And write here output from there.