# My bat file does not run pause.exe for the Password Locker project in chapter 6 of "Automate the boring stuff with python"

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords, pause

I have been trying to make the Password Locker project in chapter 6 of the book, "Automate the boring stuff with python". The project requires one to use the command prompts to get the password of any account added to the dictionary in .py file. I have been trying to run it by using win + R button, but the Command window just appears and vanishes in a blink of an eye (literally), not allowing me to copy anything from the command window to notepad. I have followed all the necessary steps like creating the folder for storing the scripts and adding the folder path to environment variables. The code is simply copied from the book, I did not try to mess with it. I can't seem to pinpoint where the problem is and it is a bit problematic as all the projects in the further chapters use the .bat file with pause.exe. Help me and I will be your slave for life (not literally). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000900/how-to-keep-a-python-script-output-window-open

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep a Python script output window open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000900/how-to-keep-a-python-script-output-window-open)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by creating a new folder on with the name Python34 on C:, also I copy the pw.py and the bat file.