# Why does my turtle window close immediately?

Tags: python-3.x, python-turtle

```
import turtle

ved_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
def square():
    ved_turtle.forward(100)
    ved_turtle.right(90)
    ved_turtle.forward(100)
    ved_turtle.right(90)
    ved_turtle.forward(100)
    ved_turtle.right(90)
    ved_turtle.forward(100)
    ved_turtle.right(90)

elephant_weight = 3000
ant_weight = 0.1

if elephant_weight < ant_weight:
    square()
else:
    ved_turtle.forward(0)
```

Why does my turtle window close immediately after opening in the community edition of Visual Studio 2019, but it does not close immediately in repl.it ?

Comment: It might have something to do with your python installation on your pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `input()` at the end of the script to make it wait for the Enter key.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000900/how-to-keep-a-python-script-output-window-open