# Hide terminal when running Python

Tags: python, linux

I use Linux. I want to hide the terminal, that is, that the command is executed in Python but invisible.

Try with two method that do not work on me (maybe I do not do it well), but I want to know if there are others. What I tried was **.pyw** and **nohup**

A quick example of the code to test is:

```
import time
import os

x = 1
While x == 1:
    os.system(f"mpg321 /beep.mp3")
    time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep a Python script output window open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000900/how-to-keep-a-python-script-output-window-open)

Comment: What's the issue with nohup? It should work.