# in python how to run file and no quit after code finished?

Tags: python

in python how to run file and **not close file after python code finished**?

for example, i try to open a excel file after code finished. But `os.startfile("filename.xlsx")` will close after finished.

`subprocess.Popen()` also don't work.

`subprocess.call()` can keep alive but the python code not finished.

Comment: Did you try `os.popen()` method ?

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000900/how-to-keep-a-python-script-output-window-open#:~:text=cmd%20%2Fk%20is%20the%20typical,want%20to%20the%20Run%20dialog. or have you tried running python -i file.py where file.py is your file