# Why do my results show in editor on my Rock, Paper, Scissors game but not when opened in command?

Tags: python

New to python and coded a simple rock, paper scissors game below. Why does the scores show after entering q while running it in visual studio code but this doesn't happen after entering q while opening the file.

```py
import random 

user_wins = 0
computer_wins = 0 

options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

while True: 
    user_input = input("Type Rock/Paper/Scissors or Q to quit: ").lower()
    if user_input == "q":
        break

    if user_input not in options:
        continue

    random_number = random.randint(0, 2)
    # Rock: 0 Paper: 1 Scissors: 2
    computer_pick = options[random_number]
    print("Computer picked", computer_pick + ".")

    if user_input == "rock" and computer_pick == "scissors":
        print("You Won!")
        user_wins += 1 
        
    elif user_input == "paper" and computer_pick == "rock":
        print("You Won!")
        user_wins += 1 
    
    elif user_input == "scissors" and computer_pick == "paper":
        print("You Won!")
        user_wins += 1 

    elif user_input == computer_pick:
        print ("It's a Draw")  

    else:
        print("You lose")
        computer_wins += 1

print("You won", user_wins, "rounds!")
print("The Computer won", computer_wins,"rounds!")
print("Thank you for playing")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "entering q after opening the file"? You launch it via command-line in any case, right?

Comment: more likely it is being run in a terminal (cmd)  window on Windows, and it closes imediattely on program end. Just add this line at the end of your program: `input("\nPress <enter> to close program")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep a Python script output window open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000900/how-to-keep-a-python-script-output-window-open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening a program as a file, the window will immediately close when the code ends - this means that as soon as q is entered, the program exits the while loop, shows the scores and closes instantly after, leaving no time for you to read it. Visual studio code doesn't have a window to close, leaving the text able to be read.

To fix this, you can add `input()` at the end of the code, meaning that the user would have to press enter to end the program.

Comment: Thank you so much. Didn't know that. That's a great help