# How can I schedule a task in Windows task Manager to run the following CMD commands

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, windows-11

I have a some commands that I want to run automatically every morning. The script is located in C:\Users\NHS\Downloads\Reward-master\Reward-master and the file name is rewards_master.py. but when I run the task, it doesn't even open the CMD window. I have checked the paths and arguments, the permissions, the triggers, and the history of the task, but I can't find any errors or warnings. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

I want to run the following

1: `Cd C:\Users\NHS\Downloads\Rewards-master\Rewards-master`

2: `python C:\Users\NHS\Downloads\Reward-master\Reward-master\rewards_master.py`

Here are the images of how i have set everything up.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: also, a total beginner in this so please go easy on me 

Comment: Your "Program/script" should be `python`

Comment: now cmd opened but closed immediately

Comment: If you want to keep the window open when your script finishes, there are various ways: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000900/how-to-keep-a-python-script-output-window-open

Comment: i tried paying around with stuff from the link but nothing worked as i am on task scheduler, I don't know how to set it up properly

Comment: Have you tried putting the *absolute path* for Python in 'Program/script'? Browsing to the installation folder and picking Python.exe should be sufficient with the Arguments and Start-In that you have.

Comment: this is what i have: https://i.imgur.com/kmAPb6K.png